# Browser sync не подгружает файлы стилей и изображения

Tags: gulp, browsersync

Не могу решить проблему. Есть gulp файл, есть browsersync. При запуске gulp прекрасно открывается index.html как на локальном компьютере, так и на удалённом устройстве.
Беда в следующем:
При запуске через Browser sync не подгружаются никакие файлы (стили, картинки). Уже что только ни пробовал, даже пути файлов пытался подобрать.
Однако при запуске через live server непосредственно из-под vs-code всё работает прекрасно. При перемещении необходимых файлов к файлу index.html всё работает, но из папок они не подключаются

```
const gulp          = require("gulp");
const browserSync   = require("browser-sync");
const sass          = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
const rename        = require("gulp-rename");
const autoprefixer  = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const cleanCSS      = require("gulp-clean-css");
const concatCss     = require('gulp-concat-css');
      
gulp.task("server", function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "src"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task("styles", function () {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/*.+(sass|scss)")
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(rename({ prefix: "", suffix: ".min" }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ cascade: false }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: "ie8"}))
        .pipe(concatCss("styles/style.css")) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/*.+(sass|scss)", gulp.parallel("styles"))
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
})

gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("watch", "server", "styles"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю с чем это связанно, но поменяв порт с дефолтного 3000 на 9000 все заработало

```
const server = () => {
    browserSync.init({
      server: {
        baseDir: pub
      },
      port: 9000
      
    })
  }
```